# Why aren't my radio button.checked comparisons working?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, powershell-studio

I have three radio buttons that I am working with. No matter which one I select it seems to default to the first one. It's working in regards to actually assigning a value, but the second radio button doesn't seem to be working.

```
if ($radDB1.Checked = $true){
    $database = 'EXDB01_005'
}
if($radDB2.Checked = $true){
    $database = 'EXDB02_005'
}
if ($radDB5.Checked = $true){
    $database = 'EXDB01_005'
}
```

They are placed inside a groupbox, which I tried to access here:

```
switch ($grpEXDatabase)
{
    $radDB1.Checked { $database = 'EXDB01_005' }
    $radDB2.Checked { $database = 'EXDB02_005' }
    $radDB5.Checked { $database = 'EXDB01_005' }
}
```

This did not work. Anyone know what's going on with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($radDB1.Checked -eq $true){
    $database = 'EXDB01_005'
}
if($radDB2.Checked -eq $true){
    $database = 'EXDB02_005'
}
if ($radDB5.Checked -eq $true){
    $database = 'EXDB01_005'
}
```

The problem with your code is that you're using "=" instead of "-eq" in your if statement. The above should work for checking the value. Otherwise using "=" assigns a value, it doesn't compare it.

Comment: Since $radDB5.Checked should be a bool, you shouldn't need to type `-eq $true` either. just `if ($radDB1.Checked){}` should work

Comment: @Sambardo true. I just wanted to make sure to point out -eq vs =. It's a really mistake to make.

Comment: For sure, it got me a ton when I first started with PS. I just wanted to add that bit on for him, and I figured it fit better as a comment than a separate answer.

Comment: @Sambardo Ended up switching to that. Thanks for the answer!